# Как отследить Android Navigation Bar в Unity?

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android, navigationbar

Разрабатываю приложение в Unity для Android. Мне нужно отследить, включена ли панель навигации и если включена, то добавить отступ в canvas для корректного отображения.
Я знаю как убрать или включить панель навигации в Android Studio и через плагин добавить его в Unity. Но не знаю как правильно отследить её активность.
На устройствах без физических клавиш можно включать/выключать панель навигации в настройках. Например на Xiaomi настройка называется "Безграничный экран". 
Каким образом можно проверить наличие физических клавиш или включённых в настройках клавиш навигации, чтобы добавить отступ в Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл вариант, который мне подходит.

```
public static void SetupAndroidTheme(int primaryARGB, int darkARGB, string label = null)
{
        #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        label = label ?? Application.productName;
        Screen.fullScreen = false;
        AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
        {
            AndroidJavaClass layoutParamsClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams");
            int flagFullscreen = layoutParamsClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_FULLSCREEN");
            int flagNotFullscreen = layoutParamsClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN");
            int flagDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds = layoutParamsClass.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS");
            AndroidJavaObject windowObject = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getWindow");
            windowObject.Call("clearFlags", flagFullscreen);
            windowObject.Call("addFlags", flagNotFullscreen);
            windowObject.Call("addFlags", flagDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
            int sdkInt = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build$VERSION").GetStatic<int>("SDK_INT");
            int lollipop = 21;
            if (sdkInt > lollipop)
            {
                windowObject.Call("setStatusBarColor", darkARGB);
                string myName = activity.Call<string>("getPackageName");
                AndroidJavaObject packageManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
                AndroidJavaObject drawable = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationIcon", myName);
                AndroidJavaObject taskDescription = new AndroidJavaObject("android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription", label, drawable.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getBitmap"), primaryARGB);
                activity.Call("setTaskDescription", taskDescription);
            }
        }));
        #endif
    }

    public static int ToARGB(Color color)
    {
        Color32 c = (Color32)color;
        byte[] b = new byte[] { c.b, c.g, c.r, c.a };
        return System.BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
    }
```

Использовать так:

```
SetupAndroidTheme(ToARGB(Color.black), ToARGB(Color.black));
```

Может пригодится и это: https://zehfernando.com/2015/unity-tidbits-changing-the-visibility-of-androids-navigation-and-status-bars-and-implementing-immersive-mode/